# How to use Synchronous XMLHttpRequest without the deprecated warning?

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I wanted to use synchronous xmlhttprequest for one of my assignments and I have searched online for solution but many are related to ajax and setting the synchronous flag to true seems to resolve the problem. However I would need to set the flag to false to get my assignment done which would cause the warning. Is there a way I could use synchronous call (i.e. setting the flag to false without warning)?

Edit: I have come to the realization that firefox has completely shut down synchronous calls on the main thread. Does it mean there is no other way around it?

Comment: You can suppress console warnings but wont mean its not still depricated.

Comment: I am assuming javascript but details on your tech stack would be helpful

Comment: It’s deprecated because it’s a terrible thing to do. You can ignore the warning and hope your visitors have old browsers or you can do the right thing.

Comment: @Ryan I do understand the significance and necessity of using async calls. But nonetheless Im having a very fundamental course and this assignment in particular does not allow any of the more advanced stuff such as ajax, jquery, etc. And the example code shown to us uses simply false sync flag. So I am trying get a way around it. If this is not going to work, I might just give up lol.